# Handling File uploads and reorder with Laravel Livewire and Filepond

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, filepond

I have a form in my application that allows users to create posts and while doing so upload multiple images to the post being created.

I am using Laravel Livewire and Filepond to achieve this.

The problem I am having is I need to allow the user to reorder the images (as it is a gallery and the order is important), and save the order in the database when the form in submitted.

Another issue I am running into is allowing a user to edit their post later. I need their pre-existing post images loaded in filepond, and also allow them to upload more, delete, and/or reorder.

When the user saves the post I need to be able to update my database and file system.

All info online is how to upload files, but no info on how to reorder, or pre-populate with pre-existing files.

Here is my current code for reference:

```
<div
    x-data=""
    x-init="
       
        FilePond.setOptions({
            allowMultiple: true,
            allowReorder: true,
            itemInsertLocation: 'after',
            server: {
                process: (fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort, transfer, options) => {
                    @this.upload('images', file, load, error, progress)
                },
                revert: (filename, load) => {
                    @this.removeUpload('images', filename, load)
                },
                load: (source, load, error, progress, abort, headers) => {
                    var myRequest = new Request(source);
                    fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
                      response.blob().then(function(myBlob) {
                        load(myBlob)
                      });
                    });
                },
            },
        });
        const pond = FilePond.create($refs.input, {
            acceptedFileTypes: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg'],
            maxFileSize: '7MB',
            allowImageCrop: true,
            allowReorder: true,
            allowImageResize: true,
            imageResizeTargetWidth: '1000px',
            imageResizeTargetHeight: '1000px',
            filePosterMaxHeight: '256px',
            files: {{ $existingImages }} // used for when editing a post and it already has images. see php component on how I set this variable
            
        });

    "
>
    <div wire:ignore wire:key="images">
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <input
                id="image-upload"
                type="file"
                x-ref="input"
                multiple
                data-allow-reorder="true"
                data-max-file-size="3MB"
                data-max-files="10"
            >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Livewire PHP component:

```
    public $images = [];
    public $existingImages;

    public function mountMedia($post) {
        if($post){
            $this->existingImages = $post->images->map(function ($image) use ($post) {
                return [
                    'source' => $image->id,
                    'options' => [
                        'type' => 'local',
                        'file' => [
                            'name' => $image->getUrl(),
                            'size' => $image->file_size,
                            'type' => $image->mime_type,
                        ],
                        'metadata' => [
                            'poster' => $image->getUrl(),
                            'position' => $image->position
                        ],
                    ],
                ];

            });
        }
    }
    public function saveImage($file, $post, $position) {
        // Create a unique random string
        $randString = Str::random(3);
        // Get time
        $time = time();
        // Set file name
        $filename = $time. '-' . $randString.'-'.auth()->user()->id;
        $extension = '.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        // Save images for gallery 
        $regImage = $file->storeAs('/'. $post->id, $filename.$extension, 'post_images');

           
        // Create a new image in db
        Image::create([
            'user_id'       => auth()->user()->id,
            'post_id'       => $post->id,
            'position'      => $position,
            'filename'      => $filename,
            'extension'     => $extension,
            'src'           => 'post_images',
            'mime_type'     => $file->getMimeType(),
            'file_size'     => $file->getSize(),
        ]);
    }

    public function saveMedia($post) {
        // Make sure user owns post
        abort_unless($post->user_id == auth()->user()->id, 403);

        // Set default position
        $position = 1;

        // Save each image
        foreach ($this->images as $file) {
           $this->saveImage($file, $post, $position);
            // Increment position for next image
            $position++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone who stumbles here. I dont think it can be done. becasue the order of the images in file pond are different from the order of the images in the temporary files array in livewire. The temporary files array is created in the order the images upload. The file pond order is the order the images were added. I've completely given up on filepond and livewire for reordering images.

Comment: See here for possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66309775/handling-pre-existing-images-when-editing-a-model-using-livewire-filepond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sorting items in Livewire I would use https://github.com/livewire/sortable.
Sortable is very easy to use.

For filepond if the original image should be used again later I would save that image as well with a relation to the edited version.

Comment: Filepond has the ability to sort. I need to know how to translate the positions of the files in  filepond to livewire when i make the save. I also need a way to combine previously up loaded images with the temp files livewire makes on upload so i can reorder and save

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRXaCfS1qj0